# Tracing code of printf() in glibc

Tags: c, printf, glibc, trace

I have downloaded source code of `glibc` (GNU `c` library), version - 2.15.90. I was tracing the code of `printf()` function. I am using tools `cscope` and `ctags` to browse through code. Following is the path I traverse to understand `printf()` function. (Here, am just mentioning function calls) :-

```
1. Opening file "glibc/stdio-common/printf.c"
2. int __printf (const char *format, ...)
3. __extern_always_inline int vfprintf (FILE *__restrict __stream, const char *__restrict __fmt, _G_va_list __ap)
4. int attribute_hidden __vfprintf_chk (FILE *s, int flag, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
5. int attribute_compat_text_section __nldbl___vfprintf_chk (FILE *s, int flag, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
```

Once I reached upto function `\__nldbl___vfprintf_chk()`, there is a call to `__vfprintf_chk()` and thus last 2 functions (mentioned in point 4 and 5) calls each other. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no such at calls, `printf` quickly jumps into [`vfprintf`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=952886b69e7fe889e738d1b8af5bd3cc390ca66d;hb=HEAD#l195) which does the real work I'd say your source code browser is acting up, glibc is pretty macro intensive.

Comment: No, OP has GCC stack-check or stack-protector or something like that enabled (probably by default by OP's distribution...) which is full of interactions with glibc and causes calls to get redirected like this...

Comment: So do you mean that vfprintf() directly calls write() system call to print the output on the screen.

Comment: Well no, vfprintf makes writes (copies) into the stdio buffer which may or may not be buffered or flushed, and may or may not be attached to stderr or stdout, which may or may not be attached to the current terminal.